# How can I embed view results right in the content region as if it's part of the content?

Tags: theming, views, entities, display-suite

I have a node type with some entity reference fields that displays teasers.  I also have a block view that takes a URL component to display related nodes that are not referenced on the node's entity reference field.  What I want is for the view results to display right under the entity reference results display as if they were nodes being referenced on the field.  The site is using display suite so there is a two column display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding Entity Views Attachment (EVA) in your view, then use it as a block-field in DS.

Comment: I did not need EVA but just using a ds block-field worked great, thanks.